# Button with JavaFX using css it change text aligmen on mouse over without :hover clause

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I have a button in JavaFx stylized with CSS, but without "button:hover" clause. The text alignment in css is set to right, but sometimes apears aligned to left. When I put mouse over button, the text alignment change from left to right and I don't have nothing in CSS about onMouseOver (or that I think ). I don't know if is a bug.

CSS:

```css
.button{
    -fx-font-size: 1em;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 -30 0; 
}

.menu, .label{
    -fx-font-size: 0.8em;
}

...

#btPlusLargo{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-image: url('../resources/plus.png');
    -fx-text-alignment: right;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: left center; 
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;    
}

...
```

In FXML

```xml
<Button id="btPlusLargo" fx:id="btEntregaTodo" layoutX="773.0" layoutY="532.0" 
        mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClickAgregaTodo" prefHeight="25.0" 
        prefWidth="150.0" stylesheets="@botones.css" text="%bt.AgregaTodo" 
        textAlignment="RIGHT" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="104.0" 
        AnchorPane.rightAnchor="9.0" />
```

Without mouse over

[image]

With mouse over (It would always have to be like that.)

[image]

Edit:
Ok, I see that it depends on the TableView above the button. If I select the Table View, I have the problem, but when I click out of TableView, it's show ok.

Edit2: It shows badly when I click on any other FXML field

Comment: I would like to see the rest of the `FXML`. Just from the looks at the bit you posted, your `FXML` structure is not correct. I am saying this because you are using an `AnchorPane` to place the `Button`.

Comment: @Sedrick This is the full FXML [link](https://pastebin.com/at35tZfx) . I made it with Scene Builder.

Comment: @Slaw I will try with the image inside the button instead as background, but I think that the text should not work so.

Comment: @Slaw It works fine as imageView instead background image

Thank's for your help